# PHP MySQL website loads very slow

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a website for Minecraft server and using Minecraft Server Status Query made by FunnyItsElmo (https://github.com/FunnyItsElmo/PHP-Minecraft-Server-Status-Query/). So the problem is then I display server list from MySQL, for test I used 4 servers, it loads page very slowly, about 15 sec.

This is code:

```
include_once 'main/serverStatus.php'; //include the class
$status = new MinecraftServerStatus(); // call the class

$sql = "SELECT id, name, ip, version FROM `servers` ORDER BY votes DESC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $page";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($dbarray = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $response = MinecraftServerStatus::query($dbarray['ip'], 25565);
    if(!$response) {
        $status = 'Offline';
    } else {
        $status = ".$response['players'].'/'.$response['max_players'].";
    }
    echo '<tr><td>'.$dbarray['id'].'</td><td>'.$dbarray['name'].'</td><td>'.$dbarray['ip'].'</td><td>'.$dbarray['version'].'</td></tr>';
}
```

Also for now I use use WampServer, so I'm asking because I dont know maybe slow loading is because of WampServer or something else. Cause when I host my website I want it to run smoothly.

Comment: Add an index with this keys `id, name, ip, version` in you database table

Comment: And basicly this `MinecraftServerStatus::query` amkes it slow, because it is an query on a remote server. Maybe do cronjob that loads this data into a local database each minute. And then get it from the local db.

Comment: as @JustOnUnderMillions states, it's best to use a cronjob. Another reason for this, is that people may use this to exploit your connection (by spamming refresh button), making you connect to the server excessively, worst case scenario, you will be blacklisted by the server you are connecting to.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions you said it's slow, because it is an query on a remote server. So if I will use host for my website, will it load page normaly, or it still will be with some delay?

Comment: I thing a `MinecraftServer` will always be an remote server, if you are not hosting it an your maschine. (and if hosting on your maschine you dont need the MinecraftServerStatus class, because you can QUEY the server directly "withour that socket_* stuff")